# laravel5.2 delete model with all relations

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, relationship, cascading-deletes

My current model has some relations. How can I delete them too, in case of model will be deleted?
This query won't delete the related models, only the 'main model'.

I use this code to call:

```
$checks = Check::where('created_at','<=', Carbon::now()
                 ->subHours(3))
                 ->with('checks')
                 ->with('results')
                 ->delete();
```

Here's my current model of Check

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($check) {
        $check->checks()->delete();
        $check->results()->delete();
    });
}
```

Results and checks contain more than one entry for each check. Meaning this to make things clear:

One check may have n `CheckResult` and may have n `CheckProcedure` (I'll of course delete all of them too).

Comment: you are calling `delete` on a query builder, not the model. If you want a model event fired, you have to call that on a model. also not sure what the eager loading is for, if you are just executing a delete statement on the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `deleted` instead of `deleting` :

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function($check)
    {
        $check->checks()->delete();
        $check->results()->delete();
    });
}
```

Also try to parse object by object from returned collection:

```
foreach($check->checks as $check_object) {
    $check_object->delete();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated code above, doesn't work. Only main model gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Like already pointed out in the comments, you are performing the delete on a query builder instead of the actual related models. i.e.

You should have

```
$check->checks->delete();
$check->results->delete();
```

instead of what you currently have.

In addition, the right way to do this assuming you are using a relational database is to use [foreign keys with cascade delete action](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: You are not looking. `checks->delete()` not  `checks()->delete()`